# Using mustache.js in conjunction with mustache.php

Tags: php, jquery, json, kohana, mustache

I am using mustache.php (Kohana's KOstache) to populate my form values with persistence. My template is something along the lines of this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="copy-billing-address"><span>My billing address is the same as my shipping address</span><br />

<label for="project[billing-organization]" class="pb-label">Organization:</label> <input type="text" name="project[billing-organization]" value="{{#field_data}}{{billing-organization}}{{/field_data}}"  />
{{#errors}}{{#billing-organization}}<span class="validation-error">{{billing-organization}}</span>{{/billing-organization}}{{/errors}}

<label for="project[billing-address-1]" class="pb-label">Address:</label> <input type="text" name="project[billing-address-1]" value="{{#field_data}}{{billing-address-1}}{{/field_data}}"  />

{{#errors}}{{#billing-address-2}}<span class="validation-error">{{billing-address-2}}</span>{{/billing-address-2}}{{/errors}}

<label for="project[billing-city]" class="pb-label">City:</label> <input type="text" name="project[billing-city]" value="{{#field_data}}{{billing-city}}{{/field_data}}"  />
{{#errors}}{{#billing-city}}<span class="validation-error">{{billing-city}}</span>{{/billing-city}}{{/errors}}
```

etc...

I'm curious to know if there is a way / what's the best way that I can access and use the mustache data that PHP is returning to populate the values of the template. For example:

```
<?php $view->jsondata = json_encode($array); ?>

//javascript
var template = $("#billing-address").innerHtml();
var data = {{jsondata}}
html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
template.innerHtml(html);
```

How can I send `{{jsondata}}` to my javascript using mustache.php?

Comment: +1 for understanding the concept of both server and client templating using the same code :)

Answer (score 2):

you need to use an XHR request to do the same or if this happens during page load store the json in a javascript variable when the page is rendered and when the page is initialized call mustache to render your markup.

in php you do something as follows: (forgive me I am not familiar with php syntax)

```
<script>
var globalData= <?php //out json_encode($array); ?></script>
```

and your template should live in a script tag as follows:

```
<script id="billing-address" type="tmpl/js" >
<input type="checkbox" id="copy-billing-address"><span>My billing address is the same as my shipping address</span><br />

<label for="project[billing-organization]" class="pb-label">Organization:</label> <input type="text" name="project[billing-organization]" value="{{#field_data}}{{billing-organization}}{{/field_data}}"  />
{{#errors}}{{#billing-organization}}<span class="validation-error">{{billing-organization}}</span>{{/billing-organization}}{{/errors}}

<label for="project[billing-address-1]" class="pb-label">Address:</label> <input type="text" name="project[billing-address-1]" value="{{#field_data}}{{billing-address-1}}{{/field_data}}"  />

{{#errors}}{{#billing-address-2}}<span class="validation-error">{{billing-address-2}}</span>{{/billing-address-2}}{{/errors}}

<label for="project[billing-city]" class="pb-label">City:</label> <input type="text" name="project[billing-city]" value="{{#field_data}}{{billing-city}}{{/field_data}}"  />
{{#errors}}{{#billing-city}}<span class="validation-error">{{billing-city}}</span>{{/billing-city}}{{/errors}}
</script>

<div id="123"> </div> //div that you want to insert the markup tp

$(document).ready(function(){
    var template = $("#billing-address").html();  //use jquery methods when possible
    html = Mustache.to_html(template, globalData);
    $("#123").html(html); 
});
```

and you shoud be good to go.

The XHR way using Jquery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.

```
$.ajax(
{
url: "getJson.php",
data: {id:123}, // data optional,
type: "GET",  //or POST depending on what you need
dataType:"json", //data you are receiving from server
success: function(jsonData)
{
var template = $("#billing-address").html();  //use jquery methods when possible
html = Mustache.to_html(template, jsonData);
$("#123").html(html);
}
});
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem with this approach is that i can't do `//out json_encode($array)` because I am using mustache.php for logicless templates

Comment: sorry I dnt follow.. Can you illustrate?

Comment: @Dave Kiss: Populate the data in you view class into a php variable, not the template, store it in a variable (script block + js variable definition). I had a issue with echoing json on the php side, for some reason it didn't echo to a js variable nicely, escaping issues, so with a close deadline I went for the XHR approach. I might try to make it right now, and post the result here. Also keep in mind, if your templates are big, it is maybe more efficient to get them with XHR, than to store everything in a js variable